# Google image search super slow

Tags: 10.10, firefox, freeze, search

I've just started using Ubuntu (10.10) so I have a reasonably fresh install.

Regardless of if I use the Firefox 4 latest beta or 3.6.13. Google image search is dead slow and sometimes intermittently freezes.

It's exceptionally slow compared to the same versions of Firefox when I was using Windows.

As an aside Microsoft's Bing doesn't freeze.

Comment: What about the regular search? Does it work well? Did you try Google Search on Windows in the same time period?

Comment: @Oxwivi - I'm actually dual booting with Windows, so it's no problem on the Windows side. Regular search is fine and as mentioned above, even Microsoft's Bing is no worry.

Comment: I was trying to evaluate if it could be possibly Google's down time. But if you say that it works properly in Windows around the same time, Google's servers are not at fault.

Comment: As @arrange says, it's generally a good idea to rule out plugins by starting firefox with `firefox -safe-mode` .

Comment: @jgbelacqua - It's a fresh install of Firefox and I don't have any plug-ins installed. I will give the safe mode a try and report back.

Comment: Ubuntu adds some plug-ins by default (unless you're downloading directly from mozilla)

Comment: @iSeth I'm not sure we should close this. [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/28415/22949) would likely solve the problem, so this question may be useful to others. (And it has a couple upvotes--this question no longer appears as unanswered.)

Answer (score 3):

Are you using any add-ons? Do you see the same behaviour if you

- close firefox
- press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> to launch the Application Launcher
- launch *clean* firefox by typing `firefox -safe-mode` and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, but from what I know, It can only depend on your internet connection (loading pictures can be rather heavy for some internet connections) or googles own servers. It has nothing to with if you use ubuntu or firefox (since firefox 3 works flawlessly for other users).

Comment: -1 As mentioned above, I don't have any problem using the same browsers on windows (same internet connection)

Comment: That was unfair, I gave an explanation valid for the question you asked. The internet connection can sometimes falter and do very rarely keep a steady speed. That means that it could be a temporary problem and therefore it CAN be because of the internet connection, even though that may not be in this case. That -1 should be undone.

Comment: You said it can "only" depend on my internet connection. That is completely false. And you also said it is nothing to do with Ubuntu or Firefox, but as indicated above it doesn't happen on the same internet connection with Windows and Firefox. So your answer is completely wrong. So are the sympathy upvoters.